# .css file not uploading to server after .less compile phpStorm 10

Tags: less, phpstorm

I have a `main.less` file that contains `@import` for a number of `.less` files that I compile into 1 `main.css` file.

My `main.less` file:

```
@import "imports/header";
@import "imports/content";
@import "imports/footer";
......
```

In phpstorm 10 I set up a file watcher to compile `main.less` into `main.css`. My deployment options are to upload changed files on explicit saves (command S)

On save, the `main.less` file gets compiled properly if I made a change to any `.less` file. Then all `.less` files that I made changes to get uploaded to the server. However, `main.css` does not. I have to manually right click it and upload to server.

I believe this is because phstorm looks for changes before the less is compiled, then compiles less and does not notice the changed `main.css`

My folder structure for my less is:

```
/stylesheets/
____/imports/
________/header.less
________/content.less
________/footer.less
________/ .........
____/main.less
____/main.css
```

My less file watcher settings are:

```
    Name: Less
    Description: Compiles .less files into .css files
    Uncheck Immediate file synchronization
    Check Track only root files
    File Type: Less
    Scope: Project Files
    Program: /usr/local/bin/lessc
    Argument: main.less
    Working directory: $FileParentDir$/stylesheets/
    Environment variables:
        i. Name: PATH
        ii. Value:
                /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.30/bin:/Users/xxx/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
    Output paths to refresh: $FileParentDir$/stylesheets/main.css
```

How do I make it so my `main.css` uploads after `main.less` has been compiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your deployment settings.

Project Settings | Deployment | Options, setting the Upload changed files automatically to the default server option to Always
And check option Upload external changes

Phpstorm will watch for changed scss and CSS files inside project directory and upload them.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm